# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1134ca968)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I started coding about 2 weeks ago and chose Swift for iOS development purposes and I am having quite a struggle with debugging. This project is a simple Tic Tac Toe app and everything runs fine except for when I tap on one of my UILabels for an X to appear.

I keep getting this Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1134ca968) error on my `canTap` and I don't know how to fix it.

```
@IBAction func onTappedGridLabel(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if gameOver {
            return
        }
        var canPlay = false
        for label in labels {
            let selectedPoint = sender.location(in: background)
            if label.frame.contains(selectedPoint) {
                if label.canTap {
                    if(xTurn) {
                        label.text = "X"
                    }
                    else {
                        label.text = "O"
                    }
                    xTurn = !xTurn
                    label.canTap = false
                    checkForWinner()
                }
            }
            if label.canTap {
                canPlay = true
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/amokuept1crt8i0/Tic%20Tac%20Toe%202.0.zip?dl=0
Here's a link with the entire project if anyone is interested. I think it's pretty short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a UILabel has no `canTap` property. Your label *subclass* GridLabel has that property, but you have not designated that your labels *in the storyboard* are instances of your label subclass, so they are just ordinary labels.

In other words, you have this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel0: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel1: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel2: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel3: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel4: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel5: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel6: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel7: GridLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gridLabel8: GridLabel!
var labels = [GridLabel]()
```

But you are lying in every one of those lines. *None* of your labels is a GridLabel. They are all ordinary UILabels. Hence, as soon as you try to access the `canTap` of one of them, you crash.

In the storyboard, select the nine grid labels and, in the Identity inspector, change their class to GridLabel. Problem solved.

Comment: Incidentally, what you're doing, giving each label its own outlet and then assembling them into an array, is silly. You can just use an outlet collection so that you get an array from the start, automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much, such a silly mistake can ruin everything. It worked!

Comment: Actually it’s surprising that the runtime didn’t report more clearly what the issue was.

Comment: saved few hours for me, thanks, @matt

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoOleksandr Cool, this just shows you never know how helpful an answer will be to someone in the future!